# Finding Length of Segments of Parallelogram Edges

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I need help on a problem regarding a parallelogram and finding an altitude on it.  The problem goes like this:

Given: $EI$ and $EY$ are altitudes of the parallelogram $EMLJ$.  $EJ=20$; $EM=30$; $EI=24$. Find $YL$

[image]

I was able to find $MI$ because of Pythagorean triples which resulted in finding $IL$ with subtraction if that helps give any leads or make the picture more understood.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$YL=LJ-YJ=30-YJ $$

$$YJ=20\cos (\theta) $$

$$\cos (\theta)=\frac {18}{30}=\frac {3}{5}$$

You will get $18$.

Comment: where exactly did you get the idea of the cosine from?

Comment: In each triangle with right angle, one should think cos sin tan.

Comment: I see now thank you very much

Comment: Once I solved the problem out, my final answer ended as 16, such a slight difference suggests one of us made a simple error?  Once I solved for theta from the cosine part I got ~53.1 which I then used with sine for the triangle EJY.  that equation ended up as:                                sin(53.1...) = x/20   once solved x = 16.  I didn't round the cosine number.

Comment: @lizzie Are you using degrees or radians.

Comment: degrees, but when I use radians I also get 16

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

You can find $EY$ because
$$
area = EY\cdot JL = EI\cdot ML.
$$
Then you can find $JY$ by Pythagoras' theorem and finally $YL$.